# Javascript audio play promise doesn't catch error after redirect

Tags: javascript, audio, promise

In Chrome, the following code attempts to load audio from a nonexistent resource. It alerts "caught error".

```
var audio_player = new Audio("/404/");  // url returns status code 404
var play_promise = audio_player.play();
play_promise.then(function () {
    alert('playing');
}).catch(function (reason) {
    alert('caught error');
});
```

However, when hitting a url that redirects to a url that returns a 404 status code, the play promise doesn't execute either block. The promise status is perpetually "pending."

```
var audio_player = new Audio("/redirect-to-404/");
var play_promise = audio_player.play();
play_promise.then(function () {
    alert('playing');
}).catch(function (reason) {
    alert('caught error');
});
```

Is this a bug? Or is there some way to make the play promise handle redirects?

Comment: looking at the specs for Audio#play, there's nothing in it regarding what the promise should do if the url when creating the element is 404 (directly or indirectly) - the only reasons for rejection are "NotAllowedError", or "NotSupportedError" - I think the fact that .play returns a promise at all in either case is the bug (firefox and edge, for example, do not return a promise in either of the above cases)